# Issue with css inclusion in my angular app (NOT angular-cli)

Tags: html, css, angular, razor, webpack

I was trying to import bootstrap's css and material design's one into my angular application but i found at the same time an issue and a compromise.

- If I include them with "link href" in my index.cshtml file, I get as
  result that this prevents my angular app from loading.
- If I include them with @include into my main .css file (which is
  called by `require("style-loader!./styles.css");` ), it actually
  works but this prevents my app from parallel .css download and the
  result is that - yes, it works - but that slows my app a lot.

I saw that lot of people include them into the proper angular-cli json file but my app is **not an angular cli application** so I actually can't do that.

So the question is: **can you suggest me what's the best way and the best practice to include the css in a non-angular cli application?**

OTHER INFORMATIONS:

- I am using also webpack, don't know if this changes or means something for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing good to know about the angular CLI is that in the background it makes a call to webpack to bundle your application with bootstrap

(if you put the proper line in the angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

)

As you are not using the angular.cli.json file, you have to directly import the bootstrap framework with webpack. A link which might help you to import boostrap with webpack : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

I hope it will be helpfull !

Comment: Thank you very much matirmv! I find your answer very helpful! By the way, i've got an other question that i hope you can answer...Referring to the point explained in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-compiled-css I think i can get a general "lesson" on how to import in the best way also other css files (so, i think i can do this also with non-bootstrap css files).
Do you know if this kind of import supports parallel css download? I mean, is this import way faster and lighter?

Comment: When you use webpack, it bundles your all application into one javascript bundle which contains all your ressources. In fact when your application is downloaded by the client, the binding to the style has already been done by webpack. To bundle properly the .css files, you just have to use the proper loaders with pack like css-loader and style-loader. i suggest your to read this little article https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! :)